# Adding If else condition in xsl stylesheet?

Tags: java, html, xslt

I am using xslt1 This is chunk of my xsl stylesheet now I Want to add condtion in that if value of account status is closed then change background color to red else green ? How can we achieve that here

```
 <th>
        Account Status:-
    </th>
    <td>

        <xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT-STATUS" />

    </td>
```

Comment: It partly depends on the XSLT version your XSLT processor supports, with XSLT 2 or later there is an XPath expression `if (exp1) then exp2 else exp3` you could use in an attribute value template e.g. `<th style="background-color: {if (ACCOUNT-STATUS = 'closed') then 'red' else 'green'};">...</th>`. In XSLT 1 you would need to use `xsl:choose/xsl:when` at the XSLT level.

Comment: Its xslt 1 ,how to write for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1, you can use

```
<th>
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
     <xsl:text>background-color: </xsl:text>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ACCOUNT-STATUS = 'closed'">red</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>green</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT-STATUS" />
</th>
```

Comment: what if I want to write some text inside that background color ?? is there any option

Comment: @NiteshBhushan, use the `xsl:value-of` you originally had, see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do something like

```
<th class="account-status-{ACCOUNT-STATUS}">...</th>
```

And then set up CSS styles named `account-status-open` and `account-status-closed`.